# Lium speaker diarization: could not find or load main class

Tags: java, speaker

On Lium official website, method of converting .seg file to ctl file is described [here](http://www-lium.univ-lemans.fr/diarization/doku.php/howto#how_to_convert_a_seg_file_in_ctl_file). But When I tried to use the same command, it raises the following error:

*Error: Could not find or load main class fr.lium.spkDiarization.tools.SPrintSeg*

Similar error raises for many other tool commands such as *MDecode* and *SMergeModel* etc. *tools.SMergeModel* command has been even used in make_gender_ubm.sh within LIUM src files (lium_spkdiarization-8.4.1.src/fr/lium/spkDiarization/system/ester2/make_gender_ubm.sh)

Can anyone guide please?

Best Regards

Comment: Show us the precise command that you are running at the command line.

Comment: java -cp LIUM_SpkDiarization.jar fr.lium.spkDiarization.tools.SPrintSeg --help --sInputMask=SH4_INT2.seg --sOutputMask=SH4_INT2.ctl --sOutputFormat=ctl SH4_INT2

Comment: Is `LIUM_SpkDiarization.jar` in the current directory when you run that command?

Comment: Yes. Most of the commands like MSegInit, MTrainInit, MTrainEM and tools.Wave2FeatureSet and are working fine.

Comment: Use `jar tf LIUM_SpkDiarization.jar | grep SPrintSeg.class` to see if the class you are trying to run is in the correct place.

Comment: Class name in current jar is PrintSeg only. Thanks a lot for your help. It's working now.